# Ionic Framework Facebook SDK integration : Display Page Plugin Ionic

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new to the Ionic Framework. I've just integrated the Facebook SDK using this tutorial http://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html.

Now I want to display a Facebook Page inside a tab template. I'm trying to integrate a page using the JavaScript shown in in this Facebook tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin, but it only works in the browser, not in the actual application when run in Android.

Does anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My work around was to put the Facebook code on a php page uploaded to my server and it works really well within an iframe within the app. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it - but it works well :)

If you need it to be dynamic you can even push the variable through and get it in php using

```
$fb = $_GET["fb"];
```

Comment: the iframe method works really well thanks to you sir !